# Most appropriate exception for a collection not being initialised?

Tags: .net, exception, range, collections

What is the most appropriate .Net exception type for when you have a class which must have its collection property initialised with at least one item?

I'm thinking that it would be an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` but is there something more appropriate based on a collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always create your own `MyCollectionNotInitialized` exception. I think it is better than using any not suitable exception.

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that I had already considered writing my own custom exception but I'm specifically looking for the most appropriate standard .Net exception type. +1 for suggestion though.

Comment: +1 for creating your own exception.  This sounds pretty specific to your app so creating your own exception would be the way I would go.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, you can have a look at `System.Linq.Queryable.Single` method, which is an extension method to `IQueryable` interface and throws `InvalidOperationException` in case there are more than one elements in the collection.
IMHO, `InvalidOperationException` is worse choice than `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, but I assume since Microsoft has used `InvalidOperationException`, it seems there is no relevant exception class in .NET.